# How can show categories products in home page?

Tags: django

I want to show my all products row by row on the home page category-wise. Suppose, before starting a new row will have a heading(category name) and then will show all products according to the product category and then again will be starting a new row with a heading according to category. ***How can I do it?*** **I applied the 3/4 methods but didn't work.** Bellow, I've shown one of the methods. It doesn't work properly. Please help me.

***views.py:***

```
def home(request):
    all_products = Products.objects.all()

    context ={
        "all_products":all_products,
    }
    return render(request,'home.html', context)
```

***model.py:***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

class Products(models.Model):
    product_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to = "1_products_img")
    product_title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length = 250)
    product_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    offer_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True)


    product_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="categoty_related_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

***context_processors.py:***

```
from .models import Category

def categories(request):
    return {"categories":Category.objects.all()}
```

***template:***

```
{% for products in all_products %}
<h4 class="text-start montserrat_alternates_font ">{{products.product_category}}</h4>
<hr>

<!--- product card --->

<div class="col mb-5">
    <div class="card h-100">

        <!-- Sale badge-->
        {% if products.offer_price != None %}
        <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">
            SALE
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- Product image-->
        <img class="card-img-top" style="height:150px;" src="{{products.product_image.url}}" alt="..." />
        <!-- Product details-->
        <div class="card-body ">
            <div class="text-center">
                <!-- Product name-->
                <h5 class="fw-bolder product_title" style="">{{products.product_title}}</h5>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your thinking a bit :)
The easiest approach is to think from bigger "items" (like your `Category`) to smaller (`Product`).

Firstfully, use singular naming for models, like `Product` (without 's', just like you did with `Category`), because otherwise you will end up with confusing setting. Also, don't name fields with your model's name unless it's really necessary, `product_category` should be simply `category` and so on.

Secondly, open big `for` loop with `Category` that you pass as classic view's context:

```
def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    context = {
        "categories": categories,
    }
    return render(request,'home.html', context)
```

Then look at your ForeignKey field in `Product`:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="products", ...)
```

The key is to use `related name` properly. In your template, try logic like this (using `related_name` smoothly in reversed relationship):

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.title }}

    {% for product in category.products.all %}
        {{ product.title }} - {{ product.price }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't set `related_name`, then it would be accessible with `<model_name>_set.all()`, in this case `product_set.all()` (in templates without brackets, of course). Anyway, it will work like a charm :)